# How to create a count in this T-SQL statement in order to get the result in INT value

Tags: sql, t-sql

Good morning,

I have this query in PL/SQL, but when I declare the count I get an error, I am declaring it in the query that I make after declaring the variables, I don't know if I have to create a new one...

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT COUNT(name)
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
--WHERE name --NOT IN ('master','tempdb', 'msdb' )

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = '
     
     SELECT '''  + @DB_Name + ''' AS DatabaseName,
       ''guest'' AS Database_User,
       [permission_name],
       [state_desc]
FROM ' +@DB_Name+ '.sys.database_permissions
WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'')
  AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%''
  AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT'''


     
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Error code:
Msg 102, Level 15, Status 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '4.

End time: 2021-06-21T11:45:39.7206852+02:00

I want to be able to count these values with the above query.

[image: I want to be able to count these values with the above query.]

Comment: This looks like Microsoft SQL Server to me, which uses T-SQL, not PL/SQL.  If you're getting and error message, please include it in the question!

Comment: Why are you counting `name` at all? Surely you want one row per name in the cursor? At present your cursor has one row with an integer, rather than n rows each with a name...

Comment: I think you think that `SELECT COUNT(name)
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases` return a different result set to what it does. Also, don't use those old views; they are for compatibility for much older SQL Server 2000 databases. [sys.sysdatabases (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdatabases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message comes from the fact that your cursor doesn't have a name in each row, it has a count of databases.

This means that when you create your @command you have this...

```
FROM ' +@DB_Name+ '.sys.database_permissions

=>

FROM 4.sys.database_permissions
```

And clearly having a `4` there makes no sense.

Your cursor should be...

```
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
    --WHERE name --NOT IN ('master','tempdb', 'msdb' )
```

If you want to count the number of permissions, and total them up, I'd avoid a cursor and use UNION ALL to combine the multiple source tablea into something like something like this...

```
DECLARE @permissions nvarchar(MAX) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT
    @permissions = STRING_AGG(N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.database_permissions', N' UNION ALL ')
FROM
    MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
--WHERE name --NOT IN ('master','tempdb', 'msdb' )

 SELECT
    @Command = '
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM (' + @permissions + ') AS permissions
        WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'')
        AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%''
        AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT''
     '

 EXEC sp_executesql @Command
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the column name I get(no column name)

Comment: @kriker your comment isn't clear. Please provided more details and an example of debugging.

Comment: @kriker Here's an example of this pattern working...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=740fb7a21f286bff4207599607018b83  (Note, don't try to run it for all databases on that site, it has thousands of them.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, which takes your query literally, would be to use a `UNION ALL` and the `COUNT` the rows returned dataset. I use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method here, due to not knowing if you are on SQL Server 2017+ or not:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF NCHAR(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Users' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM (' + @CRLF +
           STUFF((SELECT N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(d.[name],'''') + N' AS DatabaseName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       ''guest'' AS Database_User,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       [permission_name],' + @CRLF +
                         N'       [state_desc]' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.[name])  + '.sys.database_permissions' + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'')' + @CRLF +
                         N'  AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%''' + @CRLF +
                         N'  AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT'''
                  FROM sys.databases d
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,N'') + N') AS C;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```